# running gitlabci behind apache proxy

Tags: apache, gitlab, mod-proxy, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I have an ubuntu 14.04 VM on my internal network that is running the new version of Gitlab version 8. In order to get to my gitlab instance i have another ubuntu vm with apache that serves almost like a router. All requests go to this VM and then i use m_proxy to pass through the connection to the correct internal ip based on hostname. Gitlab itself works great. Im able to do all my pushes and pull and everything is peachy however i am having some issues with configuring the CI that is baked into the new version. I followed the directions from here https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ci-multi-runner/blob/master/docs/install/linux-repository.md
I have the runner installed but i cannot seem to get it registered. I setup a new hostname for gitlabci which points to the same server as the main gitlab instance. I then put that url into the `ci_external_url` option as specified here https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/omnibus-gitlab/tree/master/doc/gitlab-ci

I created a new vhost on my apache instance and it looks like this

```
<VirtualHost *:80 *:3000 *:8081>
  ServerName gitlabci.example.com
<Proxy *>
  AddDefaultCharset off 
  Order deny,allow
  Allow from all 
</Proxy>

  <Location />
   ProxyPass http://internal.ip/
   ProxyPassReverse http://internal.ip/
  </Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

I omitted the domain names and the internal IPS from the code but that's the gist of what the vhost looks like.

When trying to register the runner i enter the url for the gitlabci instance and then i next passed the token that gitlab gave me and the description and then it says that it cant register the runner and that perhaps i'm having network issues.

I feel as if there's a port i don't know about that i need to be listening for instead of the ones i have listed but i couldn't find much documentation on that. I would appreciate any help that someone can give. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by adding /ci to the url for CI no kidding